# How to load file into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table that should be updated according the file that user uploads.
In other words, I would like user to be able to upload a file, and change the contents of the table according to file content.
The file size can be several MB.
What are my options ?
Do I must to upload the file to a server, or it can be done in client side ? Thanks !

Comment: Are you saying you want the contents of the uploaded file to populate the HTML table?

Comment: Kind of. I want to change the background of table cells based on file's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot manipulate files on the client side. Unless you convince the user to turn off security for your application.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Could you give a pointer to some example of uploading to the server ?

Comment: You should use a form with <input type="file"> in it. Just search for it, you will find an abundance of examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the file in pre-determined XML format and then bind HTML table to XML data island.

See this example:
http://www.users.cloud9.net/~bradmcc/xmlisland.html

Although, I'm not sure if this technique works with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this would be to upload the file to the server, process the file there and then return a set of values which need to be inserted into your page.